# which slider view controller can be added for iPhone

Tags: ios

i need to add a slide view controller like Facebook app.

which is a best third party slide view controller can be add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of api's are available in github and as well as cocoa controls. I used sidebarviewcontroller api form git hub for my two applications. Its working fine with latest version of iOS 8 also. Please check following api, and its very easy to integrate to XCode.

https://github.com/izqui/SHSidebarController

All the best!!